# How `git checkout -` works on low level

Tags: git, git-plumbing

How can I get a previous branch/commit using Git plumbing commands or status files?

Edit: The question is - how can I get this information (the previous branch or commit) without performing an actual checkout? This is needed for a tool which works on top of Git, not for a regular Git scenario.

Comment: With `git reflog`?

Comment: @jthill thank you. `reflog` looks promising. Do you know an exact command to get the previous branch?

Comment: "previous branch"? Previous in which context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By taking a look in the [code](https://github.com/git/git/blob/cb5918aa0d50f50e83787f65c2ddc3dcb10159fe/builtin/checkout.c#L989):

```
if (!strcmp(arg, "-"))
    arg = "@{-1}";
```

The way to access the previously checked out branches is documented in [revisions doc on @{-n}](https://git-scm.com/docs/revisions#revisions--ltngteg-1)

Now, to resolve the branch name behind `@{-n}`, the solution is [`git check-ref-format --branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ref-format):

> With the `--branch` option, it expands the “previous branch syntax” `@{-n}`. For example, `@{-1}` is a way to refer the last branch you were on. This option should be used by porcelains to accept this syntax anywhere a branch name is expected, so they can act as if you typed the branch name.

```
$ git check-ref-format --branch @{-1}
my_branch
$ git check-ref-format --branch @{-2}
master
```

There is also the `git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name` solution:

```
$ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name @{-1}
refs/heads/my_branch
$ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name @{-2}
refs/heads/master
```

Comment: This is pretty much the same as `git checkout -`. The question is - how can I get this information (the previous branch) without performing an actual checkout?

Comment: `git check-ref-format --branch @{-1}` is what I was looking for. Thank you, @zigarn!